# Redundant “necessarily”?

Tags: word-usage

I just heard this on BBC Radio 4: “We could not necessarily have predicted the pandemic”. Am I right in thinking that “necessarily” is meaningless in this context?

Comment: I would say that 'necessarily' (inevitably) adds emphasis. The pandemic was not, said the speaker, a necessary consequence of things already known.

Comment: Check Merriam-Webster's definition of the word (Sense 2 seems to apply here: _as a logical result or consequence._ See if this meaning applies in the context.

Comment: Not meaningless, because there were articles in the literature that warned about a coronavirus epidemic.

Comment: These three comments are the ingredients of a good answer; I shall resist the temptation to synthesise and plagiarise. Over to you ...

Comment: @Anton - the question is borderline off-topic in my opinion; it might merit a vote to move it to ELL, and therefore more inviting of comments than answers.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I realise that I tend to laxness but I thought the combination of emphasis, necessity, meaning and implication to be quite interesting.

Comment: I think it brings up some interesting use questions, “we could not have predicted the pandemic” is quite different, virtually the opposite, of “we could not necessarily have predicted . . .—-but we could have done so, had we taken care, read the literature, taken it seriously . . .”. @Anton, take it if you want it.

Comment: My view is that the word "necessarily" isn't necessarily meaningless, but it necessarily makes the sentence meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

No, in this context, *necessarily* is a **hedging** term; it isn't meaningless or redundant.

If you remove the term you get this:

- We could not [ ] have predicted the pandemic

This states that prediction was impossible.

Substantiating this requires showing that not only was it the case that no one predicted it, but also that no one was *able* to predict it.

You could refute this modified statement by postulating a set of research labs that had been battling with similar strains in years past. Clearly, prediction was not impossible. You could also point to actual predictions such as the following, which was quoted by [DH Web Desk](https://www.deccanherald.com/national/did-this-book-predict-coronavirus-outbreak-12-years-ago-813675.html), citing Brown's book "End of Days":

> In around 2020 a severe pneumonia-like illness will spread throughout the globe, attacking the lungs and the bronchial tubes and resisting all known treatments.

With *necessarily* in your quote, the author is not stating that prediction was impossible. The claim is instead that the *certainty* of such a prediction was impossible. To use the phrasing suggested by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/necessarily), the claim is that prediction was not *inevitable*.

Substantiating this (original) version requires just one person who didn't predict the pandemic. Conversely, to refute it, you would need to show that every person would have predicted the pandemic.

The original version (with 'necessarily') has a burden of proof that is so light as to be trivial, whereas deleting 'necessarily' makes the burden of proof so onerous as to be (almost?) impossible.

Answer (score 0):

> I just heard this on BBC Radio 4: “We could not necessarily have predicted the pandemic”. Am I right in thinking that “necessarily” is meaningless in this context?

No, I don’t think “necessarily” is meaningless. It changes the likelihood the speaker imputes to the question whether the pandemic was predictable.

The world had two 21st century coronavirus events: SARS-COV1 and MERS. Some coronaviruses also circulate among humans as one cause of the common cold. That a novel coronavirus could become pandemic was a possibility, *not necessarily predictable* but not beyond imagination.

With the mere snippet, it is not possible to know what the writer intended. But *necessarily* is suggestive of possibility.

Here’s a snippet from Ngram:

> Bryan J. Rooney, ‎Annabel Ness Evans · 2018 · ‎Preview · ‎More editions
> A statistically significant effect is not necessarily important and may not be worth the attention of researchers.

Clearly *necessarily* is essential to the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

Let's take the sentence at face value and analyse it. To make its logical structure clearer, let's use P to stand for our prediction of the pandemic. Given that *could* expresses possibility, the sentence says:

> It was not possible that P was necessary.

As necessity and possibility are interdefinable,  this is logically equivalent to:

> It was necessary that P was not necessary.

Is that what was intended? Almost certainly not: outside some highly specialised contexts, people very rarely think or speak of nested necessities/possibilites. The original use of *necessarily* is thus not meaningless, but, taken at face value, gives the sentence a mind-boggling meaning that is far from what was probably intended. The obvious solution is not to take *necessarily* in the original formulation at face value. In fact, one is most likely to get the intended meaning if one simply ignores its presence.